# Replace arabic characters in webview

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, character, arabic

I have a webview which shows a text containing arabic characters. If i replace a character with another in the html file, the character is shown disconnected in the result. For example, if the character 'ل' is replaced with "ب' in the word 'سلام' , characters are disconnected in the result: 'س ب ام'. I searched a lot. If i replace all the characters in the word with the unicode characters, the result is shown correctly. However my file is large. What is the best way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right unicode codepoint?  There's several forms of unicode code points for each arabic letter, some of which purposely do not combine.

Comment: The first html file is correct. But i need to highlight some characters in the text. When i add the style color, the character is highlited but the it is shown disconnected.

Comment: In other words, i replace the character with the required tags in the html file: <a .......> chatacter </a>

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the new spannable (the data structure that holds styles in text on Android) is a hard break to the smoothing algorithms as it would be 2 draw text commands. In which case the best solution would be not to change anything midword

Comment: In my program in adition to highlight the text, i need to define the anchor to jump to the highlighted text. Therfore it seems that the solutions such as spnnable string does not work here. It is worth mentioning that If i add the anchor to the character, it works but results in separated characters in the word.